# External staging data of parquet returns NULL in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Everyone, I am having an external stage on `S3` where the parquet files are stored.
Now, I have created a table as `T1_D1`:

```
CREATE TABLE T1_D1(ID NUMBER(38,0),
TRANSACTION_DATE TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
PRODUCT VARCHAR(16777216))
```

Now, I am running the below script, to test whether the data I am loading is correct or not.

```
select 
$1:ID::number,
$1:PRODUCT::VARCHAR(16777216)
from @my_s3/T1/day_2_sales.parquet
(file_format => my_parq)
```

It successfully returns the `ID` numbers, whereas the product is returned as `NULL`, in all the rows.
I have even tried to run with the transaction date column but the same problem persists. (i.e) `ID` matches and returns the data correctly but timestamp values throw me `NULL`.

`$1:ID::NUMBER, $1:TRANSACTION_DATE::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,`

As an additional step i have used AWS crawler, on the source parquet files which gives me a schema of the following table as follows.

`1 id : bigint 2 transaction_date : string  3 product : string`

Comment: Have you tried using a much smaller VARCHAR size to see if it makes any difference? i.e. 2000

Comment: I have sorted out the solution @Nick.McDermaid, the problem is at the columns naming side.

Comment: It would be great if you could post details in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things i have Experimented out are as follows.

- First i have tried to test with individual columns, i.e tried to print **ID**, and **PRODUCT** column by using the following query.

`select $1:ID::number, $1:PRODUCT::VARCHAR(16777216) from @my_s3/T1/day_2_sales.parquet  (file_format => my_parq)`

```
 It returned ID's correctly but the product values are null.
```

- So i have used an AWS crawler, in order to find the data types of the source schema,  and have written the snowflake query accordingly. by changing the data types in the snowflake. But still it returns NULL.
- Then i found out that, the Naming Convention of the columns in the source parquet file are not appropriate. i.e the destination column **"ID"** is named as **"ID"** itself in source system, but where as **"PRODUCT"** is named as **"Product"** in the source parquet file. and **TRANSACTION_DATE** is named as **Transaction_Date**.
- The below Query worked successfully.

`select $1:ID::number, $1:Transaction_date::timestamp, $1:Product::varchar from @my_s3/T1/day_1_sales.parquet (file_format => my_parq)`

Comment: Thanks for returning with more details. That's really good information to know, given that the parquet reader didn't give you any clues at all.

Comment: The problem with snowflake is it doesn't throw any error explicitly, we need to figure it out whats actually going behind. in this process we learn a lot.